# How to compute the distance of a set points

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a problem about computing the distance of points. Let see my definition. I have a finite set points:

`S={a_i=(a_i1,a_i2) ∈ Ω, 1<=i<=k }`

where Ω is image domain, `i` is index of pixel.

The distance function `d` is tuned by parameter sigma that allows adjustment according to the number of points to be fitted:
[image]

Let `I:Ω->R`  given by

```
I= [200 219 226 228 228 240 243 245 245
    212 222 229 233 241 247 248 252 252
    220 226 234 239 247 250 250 255 253
    225 231 244 248 249 248 247 253 250
    233 238 251 252 254 249 242 242 235
    243 250 255 246 250 244 230 216 200
    252 255 250 231 225 211 187 166 153
    250 249 234 213 192 164 129 111 114
    236 226 195 168 138 119 93  84  91]
```

Now, I want to compute distance d with a given `sigma=3`, I want to compute the distance `d` that follows the above equation. Could you help me implement it by matlab code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is each row of `I` a "point"? Have you looked at `pdist`?

Comment: How's *ai1* and *ai2* defined?

Comment: @Dan: I think each pixel is a point. Brodroll: ai1 and ai2 is two coordinate of a pixel. For example, when you said pixel a that has position a1 is row and a2 is column

Comment: @user8430 but then what is `k`? Does your matrix have `k` elements or `k` columns?

Comment: @user8430 - You are correct. `ai1` and `ai2` are row and column coordinates.  I'll write an answer.

Comment: @Dan - `k` are as many row/column coordinates that you have that are defined within the image.

Comment: just a note for computing the distance: use the logarithmic sum instead of the product as it will improve numeric accuracy and speed, then just use the exponential to get the actual product

Comment: @NikosM. - Yup.  Doing that right now.  I was actually writing that up as we speak.

Comment: @user8430 - BTW, `x` looks like they are coordinates in the image.  They actually have nothing to do with the intensities themselves... so this is actually independent of image intensities, but the size of the image itself.

Comment: @user8430 - Already read it :)

Comment: I think if we are working in location, it is not make sense. I think the author wants to do it in pixel intensity. Because he wants to find the edge. With d=0, then he said that the region is edge region in image

Comment: @user8430 - If that's the case, then what is `x1` and `x2`?  If `x1` and `x2` are intensities, then why would we be subtracting this with row / column locations `ai1` `ai2`?  We would be subtracting two unlike things.

Comment: I think that x1 and x2 is same with a_i1 and a_i2. It looks like the location of pixel x (row, column)

Comment: @user8430 - Correct.  Also, `omega` is defined over spatial coordinates, and `x1`, `x2` is defined within the set `omega`... therefore, spatial coordinates.

Comment: @user8430 - Can't view the paper.  It's giving me a 404 error.

Comment: @user8430 - Read it.  It's the same thing.  What is meant by `d ~ 0` is that if you use this distance function where the majority of points you choose in the set belong to the contour, then the resulting outputs are going to be a lot of zeros.  Basically, `ai1` and `ai2` are "anchor points".  The output distance matrix will define each pair of `ai1` and `ai2` to be zero.  Let me update my post and I'll show you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm interpreting the equation right, you have `k` row/column coordinates.  For each pair of row/column coordinates you have `ai1,ai2`, you wish to compute the term inside the brackets of the expression in your post.  This results in `k` matrices, and you'll then have a matrix `d` such that it's the same size as your image and it computes the **product** of all of these matrices together.

However, for numerical stability, if you take the logarithmic sum, add up the terms, and then take the exponential of the result, you'll get the same thing and it's actually much quicker (tip of the hat goes to Nikos M. for the tip).

I'd like to note that `x` seems to be dealing with image coordinates and has nothing to do with the intensities of the image itself.  This makes sense given from what I read from the paper.  The paper seems to stress that this distance measure looks at spatial locality of pixel locations.

In terms of ease, the quickest way to get something running would be to have a `for` loop that accumulates all of the results together.

Something like this:

```
ai1 = [3, 5, 7]; %// Example row coordinates
ai2 = [6, 8, 9]; %// Example column coordinates

%// Image defined by you
I= [200 219 226 228 228 240 243 245 245
    212 222 229 233 241 247 248 252 252
    220 226 234 239 247 250 250 255 253
    225 231 244 248 249 248 247 253 250
    233 238 251 252 254 249 242 242 235
    243 250 255 246 250 244 230 216 200
    252 255 250 231 225 211 187 166 153
    250 249 234 213 192 164 129 111 114
    236 226 195 168 138 119 93  84  91];

sigma = 3; %// Defined by you

out = zeros(size(I)); %// Define output image

%// Define 2D grid of points
[x1,x2] = ndgrid(1:size(I,1), 1:size(I,2));

for idx = 1 : numel(ai1) %// Or numel(ai2) as it's the same size
    %// Compute internal function
    p = 1 - exp(-(x1 - ai1(idx)).^2 / (2*sigma^2)).*exp(-(x2 - ai2(idx)).^2 / (2*sigma^2));

    %// Accumulate
    out = out + log(p);
end

%// Take anti-log
out = exp(out);
```

---

Bear in mind that the above notation is with respect to **1-indexing** as MATLAB starts indexing things at 1.  Traditionally, image indexing starts at 0, so if you want to start at 0, simply offset `ai1` and `ai2` by 1, and also in the `ndgrid` call, subtract the values by 1.

So, modify here:

```
ai1 = [3, 5, 7] - 1; %// Example row coordinates
ai2 = [6, 8, 9] - 1; %// Example column coordinates
```

... and here:

```
%// Define 2D grid of points
[x1,x2] = ndgrid(1:size(I,1), 1:size(I,2));
x1 = x1 - 1; x2 = x2 - 1;
```

---

I'm assuming that the zero-indexing is what is desired.  As such, with the above code, I get this as the output:

```
out =

  Columns 1 through 8

    1.6849    1.1763    0.7129    0.3843    0.2042    0.1387    0.1508    0.2215
    1.5092    0.9580    0.4959    0.2025    0.0633    0.0242    0.0372    0.0784
    1.4192    0.8515    0.4004    0.1353    0.0236         0    0.0089    0.0249
    1.4240    0.8534    0.4032    0.1427    0.0348    0.0084    0.0057    0.0056
    1.5171    0.9519    0.4857    0.2003    0.0682    0.0208    0.0047         0
    1.6802    1.1341    0.6418    0.3054    0.1241    0.0424    0.0110    0.0029
    1.8866    1.3832    0.8733    0.4735    0.2227    0.0903    0.0304    0.0073
    2.1040    1.6730    1.1773    0.7265    0.3965    0.1940    0.0855    0.0342
    2.3020    1.9666    1.5312    1.0730    0.6811    0.4020    0.2315    0.1446

  Column 9

    0.3566
    0.1563
    0.0594
    0.0180
    0.0056
    0.0036
         0
    0.0199
    0.1250
```

As you can see, the row and column coordinates of what we specified in `ai1` and `ai2` are **zero** in the distance matrix while the rest of the points reflect the rough distance from each of the anchor points.  It honestly looks like a watered down version of the [distance transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform).  The zero coefficients make perfect sense.  Remember, we are taking the product of all of the `k` matrices together for the final output, and what's going to happen is that `x1` and `x2` will certainly have a `ai1` / `ai2` pair and so the subtraction in the exponent thus leads to a 1 output, and `1 - 1 = 0`, and the product of anything (except infinity) with 0 is 0.... hence the reason why there's a 0 coefficient there!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Now, I understand what is the meaning of the formula. However, you are set fixed position of a_i1 and a_i2. How to compute for all image that means a_i1 and a_i2 will move all image. That I think

Comment: Well `a_i1` and `a_i2` are probably defined as the points that belong to the contour.  That is given by you or a contour generation algorithm.  I don't have enough information about your problem to give you more.

Comment: Ok. I see it. Just compute distance at all points in contour. I can do it

Comment: @user8430 - Yup!  Just find all points that belong to the contour, find the `x` and `y` coordinates and set them to `ai1` and `ai2` respectively, then run the above code!

Comment: @user8430 - I read the paper again.  It looks like those points are the **initial** contour points that you define.  You're working with Active Contours, right?  In that case, `ai1` and `ai2` are the initial contour points defined by you, and this distance function is used in conjunction with iteratively shrinking the contour until it wraps around the boundary.  I didn't figure it out until I saw that these points were "marker sets", meaning that they are initial contour points defined by you.

Comment: Right. I am working in active contour method. Actually, I don't know the meaning of marker set. I just focus in formula. Thank you for your mention

Comment: @user8430 - No problem.  Marker set are the points that belong to the initial contour.  This is the terminology I'm familiar with because I've worked in Active Contour methods in the past.  I've implemented the classic Kass/Terzopoulos method and the Greedy based algorithm by Williams.  Cool topic btw!

Comment: Sorry, I have some misunderstand for market point. Could we chat together to make clear problem? Please go to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78819/maker-point-in-distance-formula